Is ἐπιούσιον the only neologism in the gospel? And is there any p/d list of neologisms in the NT? And the LXX?
(neologisms are only a subset of hapax-legomena but it seemed the best tag)
Apologies if I've misDuckDuckGo'd this, or should find out for myself with a Lexicon and a biro.
=========================
The Gospels
I'm interested in how/when/why each apostle (is thought to have) coined new words... in case that opens insight into how they go about establishing technical terms. Are there specific close-in devices like repetition or illustration to introduce them - that sort of thing.
Usually I'd expect one of three things:-

Juxtaposition with a familiar word, for illustration: ἐξουσία - - ἐπιούσιον
Marked or paradoxical internal contrast, for example: διεντερεύμα = ἔντερον+ῥεῦμα
Explanation, for example: καλῶς ἀπεφήναντο τἀγαθόν, οὗ πάντ᾽ ἐφίεται (Nichomachean Ethics I.1)

ἐπιούσιον doesn't show these or other obvious devices, so can there be found elsewhere in the Gospels something else writers were doing? Did they sound not a trumpet before their coinages?
==========
NT
Comparison with the NT might be productive. There is ἀρσενοκοίτης (1 Corinthians 6:9) which seems to come under the first type in close proximity to μοιχοὶ, μαλακοὶ etc ; and θεοδιδακτος (1 Thessalonians 4:9) which is explained by its contrast with the first part "concerning brotherly love you have no need for anyone to write to you".
But other examples didn't instantly present themselves.
Someone kindly uploaded a list of hapax legomena (https://community.logos.com/forums/t/66705.aspx) but it didn't distinguish which are coinages.
==========
LXX
Wikipedia lists some sources for the LXX but they aren't public domain
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Koine_Greek#Neologisms
A Greek-English Lexicon of the Septuagint. By T. Muraoka.
Words unattested outside LXX were marked as 'neologisms' in LEH, but Muraoka is more cautious about attributing the creation of forms found first in LXX to the translators' ingenuity, given the large gaps in our knowledge of non-LXX Hellenistic vocabulary and problems concerning its dating (p. xiii).
=========================

Matt 6:11 - Give us this day our daily bread
Luke 11:3 - Give us this day our daily bread


You will greatly help your cause if your quote relevant Bible passage in which the word occurs.
